# RS485 modbus incomplete packets

Tags: python, modbus, rs485

I have two usb to serial cables connected to each other on 2 different usb ports on the same pc.

The ground and A and B cables are all connected to eachother. the voltage cable is isolated.

When I send ASCII characters using a serial terminal i can communicate both ways.

But when I run a python script for a modbus slave and a master It works sometimes and sometimes it doesnt. I cannot find a pattern in when it works and when not.

I can see when it works all the sent bytes are received by the slave but when it doesnt work the slave receives atleast 1 byte but not the rest.
Then it obviously gives a CRC error and crashes.
How come some bytes are missing  through modbus and not ASCII serial terminals?

Is this a hardware problem? How can I find out? I didnt connect extra resistors.

I can show the code for the slave and master, Thanks

[image]
As you can see I have three USB-to-serial cables connected in parallel, the orange and yellow cables are the A and B cables and the black ones are the grounds cables.

The cables are these http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBRS485.htm

This is the slave code but I tried different libraries and got the same results so I doubt its the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
"""
 Modbus TestKit: Implementation of Modbus protocol in python
 (C)2009 - Luc Jean - luc.jean@gmail.com
 (C)2009 - Apidev - http://www.apidev.fr
 This is distributed under GNU LGPL license, see license.txt
"""

import sys

import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu
import serial

#PORT = 0
PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB2'

def main():
    """main"""
    logger = modbus_tk.utils.create_logger(name="console", record_format="%(message)s")

    #Create the server
    server = modbus_rtu.RtuServer(serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, xonxoff=0))

    try:
        logger.info("running...")
        logger.info("enter 'quit' for closing the server")

        server.start()

        slave_1 = server.add_slave(1)
        slave_1.add_block('0', cst.HOLDING_REGISTERS, 0, 100)
        while True:
            cmd = sys.stdin.readline()
            args = cmd.split(' ')

            if cmd.find('quit') == 0:
                sys.stdout.write('bye-bye\r\n')
                break

            elif args[0] == 'add_slave':
                slave_id = int(args[1])
                server.add_slave(slave_id)
                sys.stdout.write('done: slave %d added\r\n' % (slave_id))

            elif args[0] == 'add_block':
                slave_id = int(args[1])
                name = args[2]
                block_type = int(args[3])
                starting_address = int(args[4])
                length = int(args[5])
                slave = server.get_slave(slave_id)
                slave.add_block(name, block_type, starting_address, length)
                sys.stdout.write('done: block %s added\r\n' % (name))

            elif args[0] == 'set_values':
                slave_id = int(args[1])
                name = args[2]
                address = int(args[3])
                values = []
                for val in args[4:]:
                    values.append(int(val))
                slave = server.get_slave(slave_id)
                slave.set_values(name, address, values)
                values = slave.get_values(name, address, len(values))
                sys.stdout.write('done: values written: %s\r\n' % (str(values)))

            elif args[0] == 'get_values':
                slave_id = int(args[1])
                name = args[2]
                address = int(args[3])
                length = int(args[4])
                slave = server.get_slave(slave_id)
                values = slave.get_values(name, address, length)
                sys.stdout.write('done: values read: %s\r\n' % (str(values)))

            else:
                sys.stdout.write("unknown command %s\r\n" % (args[0]))
    finally:
        server.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: I just changed to baudrate to 115200 and the errors are way less. Is there anything else i can do?

Comment: *Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't* is not really informative. Do you mean that you sometimes get lost or wrong characters, or that in certain configurations nothing passes?

Comment: @SergeBallesta sometimes bytes are lost.

Comment: Losing some characters on a serial line communication should not be a surprise. As modbus RTU frames include a CRC, wrong bytes should give a CRC error, and end in a rejected frame. That means that a request that gets no response in a given delay should simply be issued again.

Comment: @SergeBallesta from what im seeing more than 50% of the times bytes are missing. Usually only the first byte is being sent. This is above normal.

Comment: Connecting multiple lines together without any shielding can cause noise. To make sure, you could try different speeds. If it works better at 1200 and worse at 38400, you have a hardware problem. If it works better at higher speeds, it is a software or line config problem, and you could try different stop bits values. BTW did you control that server and all slaves agree on serial line parameters?